ARP request flood
I have one modem/router connected to the Internet. I have one Linux server connected to the router with ethernet cable, two printers connected by WiFi and four phones/tablets and a Linux box also connected by WiFi.
The internal IP addresses are a class C public range with the phones/tablets using DHCP from the router.
A tcpdump shows hundreds of thousands of ARP requests for the entire IP range each and every day. The source of the ARP requests is the router.
Is it possible for this to be triggered by an external stimulus?
Can anything be done to mitigate the flood?

thousands of ARP requests for which host (IP and MAC wise) sent them? Is it mainly one same host? And what exactly do you mean by class C public range? You mean you use IPs that doesn't start with 192.168 on some of the LAN hosts? What's the subnet mask / prefix length they are configured with?

Is it possible for this to be triggered by an external stimulus? Normally a host would only send ARP request for destinations (themselves) covered by a direct route (i.e., one with no real nexthop/gateway address) (and when that route uses an interface that is not L3-only like a tun). Although technically it's possible to generate ARP requests for arbitrary IP address from the userpace (imagine a malicious arping). (But I don't think it can be "induced" by another host by the means of just sending some packet/frame.)

Albeit highly unlikely, have you perhaps made the router work in bridge mode, and somehow your ISP would offer as many public IPs (or CGNAT IPs) as requested (by your "exposed" LAN hosts)? (By CGNAT IPs I really mean any practically-private IP, not necessarily one from 100.64.0.0/10.)

home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead

Is it possible for this to be triggered by an external stimulus? there's zero information to answer any questions. Why would you not include the source device details?

The question is good, that's why I voted it  up. I did answer both questions, clearly without any ambiguity, plus mitigation techniques and suggestions. However, someone voted my answer down. I strongly advice try my advice, it can help find the source device, then it becomes easier to find a solution or more mitigation steps, although that specific was not part of the question, I did supply information to get you there.
Now, to include the source spoofed all the way from ?, that is far more difficult than what we do in corporate networks, that is more for law enforcement operations.

@MaxHaase I downvoted it. First of all, yes isn't really an answer without explanation / reasoning. Then you blindly suggests VLANs, which is more or less assuming the problem is just "the (sub)network is too big" (instead of misconfigurations and/or attack). (Similar problem in suggesting static ARP entries.) It could barely help in actually mitigating the problem by rate limiting ingress ARP traffics on each host (as in, you are not alleviating the burden posed on the links / switch). (Besides, I highly doubt that the command you gave would work, since arp isn't even an "l4proto".)

@TomYan you are absolutely right, I was a bit too quick with the segmentation, my bad for thinking of my networks.
The ARP rate limitations isn't an optimal solution, I know; I can issue commands to change 100s of devices simultaneously and quickly make adjustments, but that might not be the case for most people.
But for a small network, it can help and that's why I mentioned it.
I have updated the answer to reflect what you rightfully pointed out. Thanks!

After a second thought, the flood could be maliciously induced by a WAN neighbor that sends traffics to your router with IP addresses within your LAN subnet as the source address. It would have worked if the router doesn't have any builtin firewalling. However, it sounds more like the problem is that you "eliminated" your LAN by having the router work in bridge mode, given the fact that you seem to mean that your "LAN hosts" are assigned with public IPs...

ARP is simply trying to connect to an IP address. The reason it is doing that is something is scanning your network.
You need to perform a packet capture on both sides of the router to determine the source.
Don't tell us it's the ISP and you can't do anything. Contact the ISP and work with them to perform a correlated packet capture.

Depending on what the router and the technology is, it might be possible to "break into" the cable between the router and the ISP (e.g. with a computer that runs Linux, has two interfaces in bridge, or by using a cable tapped at RX if that's 100Base-TX) and perform the capture without cooperation from ISP

Yes, it is possible for an external stimulus to trigger a flood of ARP requests.
The causes are usually misconfigured devices, a network loop, and yes, external attackers may be attempting to probe your network for vulnerabilities.

Implement security measures like ARP inspection and rate limiting on the router to prevent excessive ARP traffic. If your router supports it, enable DAI to validate ARP packets and prevent ARP spoofing.

Use network monitoring tools to identify the source of excessive ARP requests. This will help you pinpoint the device or devices responsible.


For example, using iftop:
sudo iftop -i <network_interface>

And tcpdump:
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 arp

Look for patterns or specific IP/MAC addresses that are frequently involved.

Ensure your router's firmware is up-to-date, as newer firmware versions may have fixes for such issues.

Check each device for misconfigurations, especially those responsible for networking tasks (e.g. DHCP server, ARP table settings).

Depending which firewall you're using, "you could" configure the rules to limit ARP traffic from external sources. Adjust the rate limit (10/s) based on your network's needs.


On iptables:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p arp -m limit --limit 10/s --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT

On firewalld:
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p arp -m limit --limit 10/s --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT

then save and reload:
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

On NFTables:
sudo nft add rule inet filter input arp limit rate 10/second burst 20 packets accept

Then save the configuration:
sudo nft list ruleset > /etc/nftables.conf

UFW doesn't support ARP directly, the work-around for that is neither straightforward nor recommended.
Good luck!

my address range is 203.2.199.0/24: a class C range.

My address range is 203.2.199.0/24: a class C range.Tcpdump shows the requests as originating at the router but I  have no way of seeing what arrives at the  outside of the router to trigger them as that is my ISP. Iptables cannot do anything with traffic outside my network.The reason I suspect an external trigger is that my inbound bandwidth from my ISP is unusually high

@SDC there are no "classes" for like 30 years already. Forget this term, really. Networks are classless. Classful networks don't use netmasks (/24 or whatever), that netmask was baked into the address itself, into the first octet. Please, address the requests for clarifications up there, especially, show the examples of your ARP requests, and explain are these originated from a single host or not, and are these ask about a single host or not. Also what router it is, do you have a control of it?

@SDC: Tcpdump shows the requests as originating at the router  Why not put that in the question? Also, do you think that ARP requests are being routed from outside your network to your network by your router? If so, that should also be in the question. ARP is a Link Layer broadcast.

OK. I did the obvious and pulled the WAN plug from the router and the flood disappeared and then returned as soon as I reconnected. This confirms, I believe, that there is an external stimulus. I would love to coordinate with my ISP to track the outside of the router but they are singularly unhelpful. If I can get them to help, what should I ask for? The firewall in the router is pretty primitive so I rely on iptables. What sort of filter would help in the router?

Evidently, it's just like you have established. Before contacting the ISP, I would take a backup of the router, and update the firmware. Ultimately, reset it to factory default settings and then update the firmware.
It might save you the time/trouble/headache of having to explain to & deal with the ISP.
